# Create a Multilevel dictionary by reading the provided logfile and output the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, multi-level

Need to Create a Multilevel dictionary by reading the provided logfile and output the dictionary as

```
{"Pattern1":{"line1":"Services","line2":"0001","line3":{"include":"BFE"},"line4":{"Include":"1*1"},"line5":"0","line7":{"Include":"2*2"},"line8":{"services":["stop","pause","delete","startup"]}}, "Pattern2":{"line1":"Registry"......}, "Pattern3":{"line1":"Files"......} }
```

Logfile as below

```
Pattern1 {
    line1 "Services"
    line2 "0001"
    line3 {Include -e "BFE"}
    line4 {Include "1*1"}
    line5 0
    line6 {Include "2*2"}
    line7 {Include "3*3"}
    line8 "-d" "-c" "services:stop" "services:pause" "services:delete" "services:startup"
}

Pattern2 {
    line1 "Registry"
    line2 "0002"
    line3 0
    line4 { Include -e      "\\REGISTRY\\MACHINE\\*\\ItemData"  }
    line5 { Include "*006f006e00*" }
    line6 { Include "*" }
    line7 { Include "*" }
    line8 "-c" "-d" "registry:modify" "registry:create"
}

Pattern3 {
    line1 Files
    line2 0003
    line3 0
    line4 { Include "$Home\\" }
    line5 { Exclude $n "NT AUTHORITY" "NT System" "AUTHORITY\\ SERVICE"}
    line6 {Include "*"}
    line7 {Include "*"}
    line8 files:read files:create files:write files:delete
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you have any idea yourself? and did you have tired anything to implementing that?

Comment: There are no real obvious reasons why certain data ends up in a list and other data is ignored

Comment: Give it a try..should be more helpful to you than asking for answers..I guess, nop?

Answer (score 0):

Not precise but effortless:

```
>>> d = {"Pattern1":{"line1":"Services","line2":"0001","line3":{"include":"BFE"},
    "line4":{"Include":"1*1"},"line5":"0","line7":{"Include":"2*2"},"line8":
    {"services":["stop","pause","delete","startup"]}}, "Pattern2":
    {"line1":"Registry"}, "Pattern3":{"line1":"Files"} }
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'Pattern1': {'line1': 'Services',
              'line2': '0001',
              'line3': {'include': 'BFE'},
              'line4': {'Include': '1*1'},
              'line5': '0',
              'line7': {'Include': '2*2'},
              'line8': {'services': ['stop', 'pause', 'delete', 'startup']}},
 'Pattern2': {'line1': 'Registry'},
 'Pattern3': {'line1': 'Files'}}
```

Just for inspiration.